# Do black holes have a graviton accumulation limit?

Tags: gravity, black-holes

Black holes seem to be a sink for baryons, photons, neutrinos and gravitons.

I understand a black hole accumulating vast amounts of the first three, but will a black hole become it's own gravity wave (or something) if it eats gravitons for long enough ?

Answer (score 2):

No. When a black hole absorbs a graviton, it simply becomes more massive because the graviton has a tiny amount of energy. There is no limit to how many gravitons it can “eat”.

Comment: For my own education: in classical GR, would an incident gravity wave be partly scattered and partly absorbed by the black hole? Or maybe that should be a separate question...

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Yes. I believe the Teukolsky equation is the usual way to study scattering and absorption of waves of spin 0, 1/2, 1, and 2 by Kerr holes. Here is an example paper dealing with gravitational waves: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.3805.pdf